# Sum of all the products

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Sum of all the products of two different natural numbers less than or equal to 10 is ?

What will be the method to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To spare some typing, let us solve for $5$ instead of $10$.

Consider the multiplication table

$$\begin{matrix}
1\cdot1&1\cdot2&1\cdot3&1\cdot4&1\cdot5\\
2\cdot1&2\cdot2&2\cdot3&2\cdot4&2\cdot5\\
3\cdot1&3\cdot2&3\cdot3&3\cdot4&3\cdot5\\
4\cdot1&4\cdot2&4\cdot3&4\cdot4&4\cdot5\\
5\cdot1&5\cdot2&5\cdot3&5\cdot4&5\cdot5\\
\end{matrix}.$$

Every product appears twice, and the diagonal holds the perfect squares. At the same time, the sum of all these terms is the development of $(1+2+3+4+5)^2=15^2=225$. As the sum of squares is $55$, the requested sum of products is $(225-55)/2=85$.

---

Now we want to generalize to higher bounds.

Let $S_n=1+2+\cdots n$. As $S_{n}-S_{n-1}=n$ is a polynomial of the first degree in $n$, we can conclude that $S_n$ is a polynomial of degree at most $2$ in $n$, let $$S_n=an^2+bn$$ (there is no independent term as $S_0=0$) and $$S_n-S_{n-1}=n=(2n-1)a+b=2na-a+b.$$

By identification, $a=b=1/2$ and

$$S_n=\frac{n^2}2+\frac n2.$$

For the squares, let $T_n=1^2+2^2+\cdots n^2$ and $$T_n=an^3+bn^2+cn,$$

$$T_n-T_{n-1}=n^2=(3n^2-3n+1)a+(2n-1)b+c=3n^2+(-3a+2b)n+(a-b+c).$$
Then by identification, $a=1/3,b=1/2,c=1/6$,

$$T_n=\frac{n^2}3+\frac n2+\frac n6.$$

---

The final answer is

$$\frac{S_{10}^2-T_{10}}2=\frac{\left(\dfrac{10^2}2+\dfrac{10}2\right)^2-\dfrac{10^3}3-\dfrac{10^2}2-\dfrac{10}6}2=1320.$$

Comment: Why does $S_{n}-S_{n-1}=n$ imply that $S_n$ is at most of degree 2?

Comment: @ovi: because the first-order difference of a polynomial of degree $k$ is a polynomial of degree $k-1$, hence a cubic term would yield a quadratic term, which isn't there, and so on.

Answer (score 2):

**HINT**: $$\sum_{i,j=1 \\ i\not=j}^{10} a_ib_j=\frac{1}{2}\left[\left(\sum_{i=1}^{10}a_i\right)^2-\sum_{i=1}^{10}a_i^2\right]$$

Hope you can use the identity properly.

Comment: The square of your second sum should be above the parenthesis ?

Comment: @Zubzub Thanks for correcting. Edited it.